# Hide the tag excerpt and the filter editor with a custom tab

Tags: feature-request, new-nav, tag-wiki-excerpt

When you create a custom tab, filtering on a tag, you will see the tag excerpt. While I understand the usefulness when clicking on the tag from any other place, I don't think it is particularly useful here.

Also, I don't want to change the filter very often.

> [image: screen shot]

Can we be able to hide or collapse the tag excerpt and the filter?